# Load local images using Picasso

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview, picasso

I'm learning loading images in GridView using Picasso. I tried to load local drawable images but gridview is showing blank. I checked for solution in other post but didn't find any satisfying answer. Only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534561/implementing-picasso-library-on-custom-grid-view) solution which isn't working. Any suggestion to load local images would be much appreciated.

```css
Adapter to load images

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {};


    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }


 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

```html
Fragment having gridview

public class GridFrag extends Fragment{

      public Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.colosseum,
            R.drawable.eiffeltower, R.drawable.greatwall, R.drawable.pyramid,
            R.drawable.statue, R.drawable.tajmahal };
 
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment
  
  View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.frag_grid, null);
  
  GridView gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
       gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity()));
        
       return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your array to `ImageAdapter`. Your `mThumbIds` array is **empty** in Adapter.

Change you code with following:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;


// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.colosseum,
        R.drawable.eiffeltower, R.drawable.greatwall, R.drawable.pyramid,
        R.drawable.statue, R.drawable.tajmahal };


public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

Comment: Damn good answer. I should have thought of it myself. Thanks so much man. @astuter

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(new File("YOUR IMAGE FILE PATH"));
Picasso.with(mContext).load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.landscape_1).into("YOUR IMAGE VIEW");
```

placeholder for showing sample image while actual image is loading by picasso.

error : if the image loading fails this image should be shown